# Как сделать на php+msql смену пароля без перезагрузки страницы пользователя

Tags: php

Вот прикрепленный архив:https://yadi.sk/d/Y6akoinZ3Rzv4r.
В прикрепленном архиве проект. Сама проблема в файле `pass_change.php`, который связан с файлом `user.php` Когда нажимаю сменить пароль то он не меняется в базе данных, а страница явно перезагружается.

Вот кусок кода по обновлению пароля в базе:

```
$result4 = mysqli_query($link,"UPDATE users SET password='$password' WHERE login='".$_SESSION['login']."'");
//обновляем пароль
if ($result4=='TRUE') {
//если верно, то обновляем его в сессии $_SESSION['password'] = $password;
}
}
```

Comment: Прикольно, то есть мы должны скачать проект, открыть файлы, понять что не так и потом вам объяснить? Скажите, вы хотя бы платите за это?

Comment: Думаю что он и не работает, вместо обновления пишет массив

Comment: u_mulder просто код большой а задние срочное

Comment: Добавьте ваш код в вопрос, а то в комментариях не принято как-то.  https://ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: по sql запросу вроде все правильно проверял через phpmyadmin и sql программу. Может быть в другом месте проблема?

Answer (score 0):

Пример на ajax
jQuery required;

```
<input type='password'/>
<button id='submit'>Сменить</button>

$.post(user.php?change,{data: $('input').val()},function(ajax){
console.log(ajax) //читаем как ругается сервер
})
```

====================>
    user.php

```
print_r($_POST)
new PDO(.....)

 $sql = $this->dbh->prepare("UPDATE users set password = ':password'    where username = ':username'");
 $sql->execute(array(':password' => $password, ':username' => $username));

или используйте готовый mysql driver
```

и перезагрузки мозгов и страницы у Вас небудет =)

Comment: разумеется session_start() в $_SESSION['user-name'] Вы храните имя пользователя